# Extend title background to page edge in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles, title

How can I achieve an effect like the following using Microsoft Word 2010?

[image: 1]

I want the gray background to extend up to the edge for every title but I can't achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a reasonable approximation, and I've highlighted what I used to achieve it (the margin and tab stop settings are *only* applicable to that title line):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

Word is not able to do what you seek with standard text or paragraph formatting. You will need to insert a text box and format it the way you desire.

[image]

Text boxes use absolute positioning, so you can move it where you need without issue to the paragraph or page formatting.